# C++: Vector containing shared pointer is always empty, has size 0

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, shared-ptr

So I'm working on a school project in C++. The basic idea is, that I have an area containing Tiles (200x200 Tiles).
Every Tile-Object contains a vector with shared pointers of my Creature-Class to display them in a GUI. The Project is a Simulation, so in order to simulate every Creature, we should use a vector containing every Creature. That's why I'm using shared pointers.
The Vector, that is specific for every tile is working without a problem, but the one with every Creature in it, is always empty. That's why I can't continue to work on the simulation.

That's how I place a Creature and try to insert it into the vector

```
void Presenter::placeCreature(const CreatureType& type) const {
    int x = getModel().getTerrain()->getCursorPosX();
    int y = getModel().getTerrain()->getCursorPosY();

    std::shared_ptr<Creature> creature(std::make_shared<Creature>(type));

    TileLand::Climate climate(getModel().getTerrain()
                                        ->getTileMap()[x + y * Reference::Terrain::terrainWidth].getClimate());
    if (climate == TileLand::deepSea || climate == TileLand::shallowWater) {

        if (!creature->isLandCreature()) {
            getModel().getCreatures().push_back(creature);
            getModel().getTerrain()->getTileMap()[x + y * Reference::Terrain::terrainWidth]
                .getCreaturesOnTile().push_back(creature);

            logger << INFO << "Placed Creature: " << type.getName() << " on Tile (" << x << "|" << y << ")" << ENDL;
            return;
        }

    } else {

        if (creature->isLandCreature()) {
            getModel().getCreatures().push_back(creature);
            getModel().getTerrain()->getTileMap()[x + y * Reference::Terrain::terrainWidth]
                .getCreaturesOnTile().push_back(creature);

            logger << INFO << "Placed Creature: " << type.getName() << " on Tile (" << x << "|" << y << ")" << ENDL;
            return;
        }

    }

    ui.warn("Falsche Kreatur", R"(Diese Kreatur kann auf diesem Feld nicht platziert werden!)");
    creature.reset();

}
```

That's how I did the vector for creatures per tile. Works fine.

```
class TileLand {

    public:

    ...
    private:
    const Climate climate;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Creature>> creaturesOnTile;

};
```

This is where the vector containing every creature is defined.

```
class Model {

    public:
    explicit Model(const CreatureList& creatureList);

    TerrainModel* getTerrain() const;
    CreatureList& getCreatureList();
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Creature>>& getCreatures();



    QPixmap calculateView(int sizeX, int sizeY);
    void simStep();


    private:
    CreatureList creatureList;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Creature>> creatures;
    TerrainModel* terrain;
    int stepCounter;

};
```

The Constructor of the Model-Class. This one contains the global Creature-Vector as you can see above.

```
Model::Model(const CreatureList& creatureList) : creatureList(creatureList),
                                                terrain(new TerrainModel()),
                                                stepCounter(0) {

    for (CreatureType ty : creatureList) {
        ty.getInfoInOneLine();
    }
}

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Creature>>& Model::getCreatures() {
    return creatures;
}
```

Thats where I try to do a simulation step for each creature. But I don't know what the problem is, "creatures" is always empty.

```
void Model::simStep() {
    qDebug("Creature");
    for (std::shared_ptr<biosim::Creature> cr : creatures) {
        qDebug("BIG");
        simPlants(cr);
    }
}
```

I hope someone can at least understand what my problem is I have no idea how to describe it better :/.

Comment: Based on your title, it would be very helpful to have a [mcve] that creates a vector of `shared_ptr`, does some manipulation, and shows that the vector is still empty. It's hard to help right now.

Comment: I don't see anything that's obviously wrong. There is a good chance the problem is not in the code your supplied. You will likely need to provide a [MCVE] to allow us to diagnose the problem.

Comment: How is `getModel()` (called in `Presenter::placeCreature`) declared (does it return by reference) ? Is `Model::simStep` called for the same `Model` instance as the one manipulated by `Presenter::placeCreature` ?

Comment: Model getModel() const;
Model Presenter::getModel() const { return model; }

void Presenter::simStep() {
  getModel().simStep();
 }
I think it is yeah (Sorry I dont know how to do new lines :o)

Comment: @Awesome36 : 1.  No, it isn't the same `Model`.  It is a *copy* of the same `Model`.  2.  It isn't possible to do newlines in comments.  It would be better to [edit] your question to include the code.  3.  Learn how to minimize questions before posting to SO; we don't need to see all the error checking for land vs water.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Presenter::getModel()` returns a copy of the `Model` instance, the `getModel().getCreatures().push_back(creature)` call adds a creature into the `creatures` vector of that temporary copy (not the original object). This change is then immediately lost when the temporary copy goes out of scope at the end of the statement.

Either have `Presenter::getModel()` return a reference (like you did for `Model::getCreatures()`), or just use :

```
model.getCreatures().push_back(creature);
```